# How to reset jquery datatable bStateSave for another page clicks in the menu

Tags: jquery, datatables

i am using jquery datatable for displaying list of records.To save the state of datatable **bStateSave** option is using.

i would like to clear this cookie when user clicks the another page or user will logged out. i added cookie duration for clear the cookie. But its not correct requirement. when user clicks the other page in the menu it should be cleared.

```
var oTable = $('#editable-sample').dataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [
                    [10, 50, 100],
                    [10, 50, 100] // change per page values here
                ],
                // set the initial value
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
               // "sDom": "<'row'<'col-lg-6'l><'col-lg-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-lg-6'i><'col-lg-6'p>>",
                "sDom": 'Rfrtlip',
                "bStateSave": true,
                "iCookieDuration":60,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"                    
            });
```

Anybody please guide me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using state saving in the first place then?